# Symfony2 Twig stop escaping path

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to put unescaped URL generated from path into input element.

**routing.yml**

```
profile_delete:
  pattern: /student_usun/{id}
  defaults: { _controller: YyyXXXBundle:Profile:delete }
```

**list.html.twig**

```
<input id="deleteUrl" value="{{ path('profile_delete', {id: '$'}) }}"/>
```

The result is:

```
<input id="deleteUrl" value="/student_usun/%24"/>
```

I tried `|raw` filter and also put twig code between `{% autoescape false %}` tag and result is still the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Twig doesn't come with a url_decode filter to match its [url_encode one](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/url_encode.html), so you'll need to write it.

in **src/Your/Bundle/Twig/Extension/YourExtension.php**

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Twig\Extension;

class YourExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'url_decode' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'urlDecode')
        );
    }

    /**
     * URL Decode a string
     *
     * @param string $url
     *
     * @return string The decoded URL
     */
    public function urlDecode($url)
    {
        return urldecode($url);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the extension.
     *
     * @return string The extension name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'your_extension';
    }
}
```

And then add it to your services configuration in **app/config/config.yml**

```
services:
    your.twig.extension:
        class: Your\Bundle\Twig\Extension\YourExtension
        tags:
            -  { name: twig.extension }
```

And then use it!

```
<input id="deleteUrl" value="{{ path('profile_delete', {id: '$'})|url_decode }}"/>
```

Comment: You should use Twig_Filter_Method, not Twig_Function_Method since you are building a filter.

Comment: I've named my file "`src/HQF/Twig/Extension/UrlDecode.php`". In that file I've named the class "`UrlDecodeExtension`". In that class, the function "`getName()`" returns `'url_decode_extension'`. in the file **`app/config/config.yml`**, instead of `your.twig.extension` I've used `url_decode_twig_extension`. The class declaration is `HQF\Twig\Extension\UrlDecodeExtension`. And then I've got an error saying "`Fatal error: Class 'HQF\Twig\Extension\UrlDecodeExtension' not found in /[..]/symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2612`". Any idea please?

Comment: To solve my problem, I've first used the sample explained here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html (which works flawlessly, but works only for the bundle where it's installed), then copy paste `urldecode` function. Thank you for putting me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using:

```
'url_decode' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'urlDecode')
```

and receive an error:

```
Error: addFilter() must implement interface Twig_FilterInterface, instance of Twig_Function_Method given
```

replace:

```
new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'urlDecode')"
```

with:

```
new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'urlDecode')"
```

Best

Comment: If that doesn't work, see: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html (I looked for this for about an hour now, wrote an filter extension etc.) My conclusion is that twig escapes the output even after a filters are applied, hence you always e.g. will get &amp; instead of & and therefore need to autoescape this part of your template. Hope that helps!