# How to create dynamic route with parameter in a JavaScript function?

Tags: symfony, routes, twig

One of my route is defined like this:

```
society_mybundle_searchpage:
    pattern:  /search/cp/{cp}
    defaults: { _controller: SocietyMyBundle:Search:searchByCP }
```

So it needs one parameter: `{cp}`.

Now I'd like to create a form with an input widget. So my code is like that:

```
  <form onsubmit="return search();" action="#">
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
  </form>
```

(Nothing specific, I let symfony do all the work for me). Note that this form calls a JS function: `search()`. So here's my code in twig:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function verif_formulaire(){
    /* some code to get the value of the cp */
    ...
    /* then: */
    ss="{{ path('society_mybundle_searchpage', {'cp': '+cp+'}) }}";
    return true;
}
-->
</script>
```

The output is:

```
function verif_formulaire(){
    ss="/symfony/web/app_dev.php/pizzas/search/cp/+tt+";
    return true;
}
```

This is not the output I need. I want the output to be exactly like that this:

```
function verif_formulaire(){
    ss="/symfony/web/app_dev.php/pizzas/search/cp/"+tt+"/";
    return true;
}
```

How shall I proceed?

Comment: The `path` function always encode the url. To achieve what you want to do, you will have to do some work creating a new `url_decode` function or equivalent. This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633676/symfony2-twig-stop-escaping-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was: implement a custom `url_decode` function in twig (very easy).

Then use the `format()` function.

Here's the result:

```
window.location ="{{ path('my_path', {'cp': "%s" }) | url_decode | format('"+monCP+"') | raw }}";
```

Explanation: `path('my_path', {'cp': "AAAA" })` will generate an URL like '`/mypath/cp/AAAA/`' thus `path('my_path', {'cp': "%s" })` will generate an URL like '`/mypath/cp/%s/`'

But the '`%s`' will be escaped. So I decode it through '`| url_decode`' :

```
path('my_path', {'cp': "%s" }) | url_decode
```

Will generate proper string '`/mypath/cp/%s/`'.

Then I use the `format()` function to pass a string.

Example: '`"/mypath/cp/%s/" | format('OLIVIER')`' will give '`"/mypath/cp/OLIVIER/"`'

So, here, I pass a specific string: `'"+monCP+"'` (watch carefully the quotes and double quotes).

So: '`"/mypath/cp/%s/" | format('"+monCP+"')`' will give '`/mypath/cp/"+monCP+"/`'

Last problem: this whole string is **again** escaped. This time, a classical "`| raw`" is enough.

Thus, to conclude, this:

```
var xx ="{{ path('my_path', {'cp': "%s" }) | url_decode | format('"+monCP+"') | raw }}";
```

Will result in full normal JavaScript code:

```
var xx ="/my-symfony-url/cp/"+monCP+"/";
```

This may look complex, but wow. No external JavaScript file needed. This is what I wanted. Just pure fast Symfony 2 php-generated cache. I propably could make this a Twig macro or something.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you need generate route in JS. So maybe you need a [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/README.markdown)?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I've got 2 problems: (1) it's symfony 2.0, and I'm more than surprised that we have to install external stuff just to generate URL in JS code (2) I did not find in the usage of the bundle here https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/README.markdown anywhere giving me sample of a JavaScript code which can ouput other things than "hardcoded" values (search for "You can do:" in the link i provide). Maybe it's the only solution but I dont know how I can use it.

Comment: May I ask you, maybe here, to give me a sample of "dynamic" JavaScript twig templating that could output a line like `ss="/symfony/web/app_dev.php/pizzas/search/cp/` **`"+tt+"`** `/";`

Comment: I was expecting the function `path` to behave very closely to a **`sprintf()`** function...

Comment: Actually if I do something like `{% set txt = '"+tt+"' %}` then `{{ txt|raw }}`, it correctly ouputs `"+tt+"`. So I'm very close with something like `ss="{{ path('my_path', {'cp': txt }) }}";` but the output it still escaped, giving `ss="/[blabla]/cp/%22+tt+%22";`. I've tried `|raw` almost everywhere...