# Symfony2 with typeahead.js: How to pass %QUERY to path parameter

Tags: javascript, symfony, typeahead.js

I wanna use [typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js) within my symfony2 project. Therefor i have the following javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var players = new Bloodhound({
          datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value); },
          queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          remote: "{{ path('_api_player_search', {searchterm: '%QUERY', limit: 5}) }}",
          prefetch: ''
        });

        players.initialize();

        $('#searchfield').typeahead(null, {
          displayKey: 'firstname',
          source: players.ttAdapter(),
          templates: {
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
              '{% verbatim %}<p><strong>{{firstname}}</strong> – {{lastname}}</p>{% endverbatim %}'
            )
          }
        });
    });
```

As you can see, i want to pass an url created by the twig `path` helper to the `remote:` property of the `Bloodhound()` configuration. (Later i want to use FOSJsRoutingBundle for that purpose).

The thing is now, that `Bloodhound()` do not replace the `%QUERY` placeholder in my twig expression. Is there any way to achieve this?

Your help would really be appreciated! :)

Comment: I would consider using `%QUERY` as a GET parameter

Comment: Yeah i have rewriten my method now to get searchterm as a get-parameter, not in url directly.
Now i have to replace the url in remote: with a custom ajax-function like remote:function(){...} ??

Comment: `remote: "{{ path('_api_player_search') }}?limit=5&searchterm=%QUERY"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i've found a solution:

According to @Peter Bailey's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10640249/1754242) on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633676/symfony2-twig-stop-escaping-path) i have created a custom twig extension to be able to add an url_decode filter to my `{{ path() }}` tag like `{{ path() |url_decode }}`.

This will prevent `%QUERY` to be converted to `%25QUERY`, an then it could be replaced in the rendered url by javascript.

Additionally i also add a `|raw` filter, to avoid the ampersand beeing encoded. So finally my tag looks something like this: `{{ path() |url_decode|raw }}`