# How not to escape path() in Twig Template

Tags: twig, symfony, twig-extension, twig-filter

My objective is to render a Twig Template and send the resulting HTML via API to Mailchimp to be sent out.

**My current process:**

1) create a Twig-Template `email.html.twig`.

2) `$html = $this->renderView('MyBundle:email.html.twig');`

3) `sendHtmlViaApi($html);`

**The issue:**
I need a URL to contain a Mailchimp Merge Tag String, which has to be `*|VARIABLE|*`. I do that with `{{ path('my_route', {variable : '*|VARIABLE|*'}) }}`. The desired result: `/myroute/*|VARIABLE|*`. The result I get: `/myroute/*%7CVARIABLE%7C*`.

**Already tried and failed methods:**

1) using `{% autoescape %}`

2) `|raw`

3) Twig Extension with new url_decode Filter from [Symfony2 Twig stop escaping path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633676/symfony2-twig-stop-escaping-path)

Comment: Are you positive that mailchimp does not handle the escaped url?  There is a reason for escaping.  Generating invalid url's seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

So you want Twig to stop the automatic URL encoding.

You can pass a placeholder with only letters and underscore to `path()`, so that it won't be escaped. Then you can [`replace`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/replace.html) the placeholder with the string Mailchimp expect:

```
{{ path('my_route', {variable : 'MAILCHIMP_VARIABLE'})|replace({
    'MAILCHIMP_VARIABLE': '*|VARIABLE|*'
}) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions!
In the end it was all my own fault... One of the merge tags was missing on the mailchimp-side setup, so it couldn't replace it with the desired value.
Silly me!